# request parameters contain org address

Tags: apex, visualforce, parameters

I have a custom button on account that's content source is URL. (target page uses opportunity standard controller)

In the url I specify apex page and a parameter ...?retUrl={!Account.id}

Now in the controller getParameters().get('retUrl’)
returns the id prepended with host's address.

https://xxxx.visual.force.com/001xxxxxxxxx

Is this a typical behaviour with URL buttons? 
Typically when I append parameters in apex I get only the value I provided.
Is what I observed documented anywhere? I would gladly read more on the subject.

Comment: What does the URL actually look like when you get the expanded `retUrl`? I suspect it will include the host details and that Salesforce has replaced your value with its own value.

Comment: Note that the keys in [getParameters](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_PageReference_getParameters.htm) are case insensitive and Salesforce uses [retURL](http://www.salesforcehacker.com/2014/03/auto-magical-things-you-can-do-with.html); you could confirm what Daniel Ballinger suggests by leaving out (or changing the name of) your parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely scenario here is that Salesforce is overriding your custom parameter with its default value for the`retURL` parameter. The Salesforce generated value will include the the host access in the URL.

As Keith C points out, [`PageReference.getParameters()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_PageReference_getParameters.htm) is case **insensitive**. So calling the method with the `retUrl` parameter can return the value for the `retURL` query string parameter.